# ActionController::RoutingError with OmniAuth sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I have a devise + omniauth setup using omniauth-google-oauth2. When I attempt to sign in using it, it tries to GET /o/oauth2/auth and fails. I assume this is either a route provided by omniauth or it should actually be trying to GET [google URL]/o/oauth2/auth, but I can't find any documentation on it. My configuration is mostly the same as the Devise github's instructions, except for my route and controller.

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/auth' }
```

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["SSO_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["SSO_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {
    scope: "email",
  }
```

Rails server log:

> Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for ****:52980 at 2018-04-05 18:30:17 -0500
>   I, [2018-04-05T18:30:17.678087 #6321]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
>   Started GET "/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=****.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F****%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle_oauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=****" for ****:52980 at 2018-04-05 18:30:17 -0500
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/o/oauth2/auth"):
>   ...